# Insert on MySql database contents of word file using Microsoft Office Interop Word

Tags: c#, mysql, ms-word, office-interop

I want to read a .docx file line by line and insert chapters and paragraphs of the chapter in MySql database table.

I have tried using [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word/) to read the document.

My file.docx is divided for chapters and paragraphs of the chapter

The structure of file.docx

```
Chapter 1 - Events
-alert or disservices
-significant activities

Chapter 2 – Safety
-near miss
-security checks

Chapter 3 – Training
-environment
-upkeep
```

The whole document is correctly read on debug visual studio

[image]

Now I try insert on MySql database table according with this schema

[image]

But instead on MySql database table I have these rows, that is, the whole document is inserted in each line without distinction of chapters and paragraphs

[image]

How to do resolve this?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion

My code and table structure chapter below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Application word = new Application();
        object miss = Missing.Value;
        object path = @"C:\Users\file.docx";
        object readOnly = true;
        Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss,
                                            ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                                            ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

        string totaltext = "";      //the whole document

        var ran = docs.Content;

        for (int i = 0; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
        {
            var chap = ran.Text;
            var subhead = ran.Text;
            var contents = ran.Text;

            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;
            string strSql = @"INSERT INTO Chapters (chapter, subheading, contents) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";

            using (MySqlConnection conn = 
                new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (MySqlCommand cmd = 
                    new MySqlCommand(strSql, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", chap);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", subhead);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param3", contents);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                conn.Close();
            }

            totaltext += docs.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.ToString() + "<br />";
        }

        Response.Write(totaltext);
        docs.Close();
        word.Quit();
    }
}

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `chapters`;
CREATE TABLE `chapters` (
  `chapter` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `subheading` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `contents` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong:

```cs
        var ran = docs.Content;

        for (int i = 0; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
        {
            var chap = ran.Text;
            var subhead = ran.Text;
            var contents = ran.Text;
```

You're setting `ran` to the entire contents of the document, then copying that into the `chap`, `subhead`, and `contents` variables (which are used to insert each row into the database).

You need to set `chap`, `subhead`, and `contents` to different values (based on the current Paragraph?) each time you insert a row into the database.

Comment: thanks for reply. How to do set chap, subhead, and contents to different values based on the current Paragraph?

Comment: @ChevyMarkSunderland I have no idea; I'm not familiar with the Word DOM. (I read this question for the `mysql` tag.) You may want to edit out the irrelevant details (i.e., all the MySQL stuff), refocus it just on splitting up the contents into the three parts you want, and tag it with `[ms-word]` to get attention from people who can answer it.

Comment: Okay I have inserted tag `[ms-word]` and `office-interop` in the question